# Can someone please explain the structure of this while loop?

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

I need to know why sum=0 was initialized. If it is unnecessary, I need to know a reason why.  Thanks.

The original question was: Given an input positive integer, output each digit on its own line, starting with the rightmost digit. Ex: If the input is 935, the output is:
5
3
9

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
      int number, sum=0, r;
      number = scnr.nextInt();
  
  while(number!=0) {
     r=number %10;
     System.out.println(r + "");
     number = number / 10;
  }
  /* Type your code here. */
}
```

Comment: Consider: is variable `sum` *used* anywhere in the method?

Comment: sum is not used in any logic , you can remove it. and `r-number % 10;` is the MOD operation on number by 10, Which means if you divide number by 10 what will be the reminder. e.g 935 MOD (%) 10 = 5

Comment: *"why sum=0 was initialized"* Because someone wrote the code. --- *"reason why"* Ask whoever wrote it, but they probably intended it for something, changed their minds and didn't clean it up.

Comment: @Guarav check twitter dms

Answer (score 1):

sum = 0 is not necessary because you never use it in the program, why would write a variable that you would never use? It would be like buying a TV but never using it